# images on click

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I hover a number a rating shows, but when I click on that number the rating does not stay visible.  For some reason it works fine when I user background color instead of background url.  Can someone please help me with this?

The end result should be as followed:
1 - hover an number and a rating image should appear.
2 - when a number is selected, that rating images should stay visible.
3 - when another number is selected that rating image should appear while the previous image fades.

Here is a demo [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gomab2/W3sZS/16/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

http://jsfiddle.net/uCZ6q/

HTML:

```
<div class="button">
    <a href="#"><div class="child1">1</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="child2">2</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="child3">3</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="child4">4</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class="child5">5</div></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.highlight 
{ background: url("http://cuuzo.com/level5.png") no-repeat 0 0; display: block; }

.child1:hover, .child2:hover, .child3:hover, .child4:hover, .child5:hover 
{ background: url("http://cuuzo.com/level5.png") no-repeat 0 0; }
```

Script:

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(".highlight").removeClass('highlight')
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: @ThinkingStiff  It isn't working for me outside of jsfiddle.  Here is a link to the exact same code, but for some reason it isn't functioning the same.  [link](http://cuuzo.com/button.html)  What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: @need2nobasis I'd love to help, but this isn't my answer. I just edited it. I'm sure wanovak answer you.

Comment: @wanovak can you please help me with this, I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing incorrectly. [link](http://cuuzo.com/button.html)

Comment: @need2nobasis Hi, sorry it took me a awhile to get to this. The issue that I corrected was to set the `a` to `display: block`. The reason this was necessary is because the `a` wasn't wide enough for the background to show. Make sure that the `a` is wide enough for the background to show.

Comment: @wanovak I have the display block added to my code.  My code looks exactly like the code you show above, but when I take it outside of jsfiddle, it doesn't work.  any suggestions [link]http://cuuzo.com/button.html

Comment: @need2nobasis Wrap your JavaScript in `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $("a div").removeClass('highlight')
    $(this).find("div").addClass('highlight');
});
```